# Solve intersection of the straight line with equation $y=x-a$ and the circle equation $x^2 + y^2 = 4$

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

> Find the coordinates of the points of intersection of the straight line with equation $y=x-a$ and the circle with equation $x^2 + y^2 = 4 $. Give the conditions on a for:

I did see the answer from the practice paper: the answer is *see the below

$$\left(\frac{a + \sqrt{8-a^2}}{2}, \frac{-a + \sqrt{8-a^2}}{2} \right); \left(\frac{a - \sqrt{8-a^2}}{2}, \frac{-a - \sqrt{8-a^2}}{2} \right) $$

**but I am struggling on how to solve it. can you please explain to me how to solve it. thanks :)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $y = x - a$ into $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ gives $x^2 + (x - a)^2 = 4$, which expands to $2x^2 - 2ax + a^2 - 4 = 0$. This is a quadratic equation in $x$ that you can then use the quadratic formula to solve to get $x = \frac{2a \pm \sqrt{4a^2 - 4(2)(a^2 - 4)}}{4} = \frac{2a \pm \sqrt{-4a^2 + 32}}{4} = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{8 - a^2}}{2}$, and then get $y$ from $x - a$, giving those $2$ answers you mention.

As for the conditions on $a$, note that you need $8 - a^2 \ge 0$ for $\sqrt{8 - a^2}$ to be a real value, so $a^2 \le 8$ giving $-2\sqrt{2} \le a \le 2\sqrt{2}$ as the range of valid values of $a$.

Comment: I was about to write the same answer, so +1 to you!

Comment: I still not get it about there's both x^2 and a^2, so how can solve for x. I mean like both same times.

Comment: @vjesse25 In the equation $2x^2 - 2ax + (a^2 - 4) = 0$, consider $a$ to be some fixed value. Thus, the variable is just $x$, with the equation then being in the form of $bx^2 + cx + d = 0$ with $b = 2$, $c = -2a$ and $d = a^2 - 4$. This is a quadratic equation in $x$ which you can solve using the quadratic formula to get $x = \cfrac{-c \pm \sqrt{c^2 - 4bd}}{2b}$. Substituting the values for $b$, $c$ and $d$ in gives what I show in my answer (note I just added a bit more detail).

Comment: ohh!! yesss!! thank you very much for helping me! you are so extremely genius! XD

Answer (score 3):

Here, a figure showing the circle and lines will surely help:

[image]

solve

$$x^2+y^2 = 4\ {\rm and} y = x - a$$

so

$$(y+a)^2 + y^2 = 4$$

and use the quadratic equation to get two solutions.